# Use sed to replace elements with another but only under a condition

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file containing lines in the form of:

Product, Brand, Cost, Comment, Location, Rating

I want to change the separating "," to a new character ";"

I've tried using sed command such as ` sed 's/,/;/g' prod.txt
But it also changes the commas present in the data ("Comments", "Brand" and the other columns) !

I could use csvkit but it would help me to use more general basic tools like sed, tr, grep, cut etc because I will have to generalize this problem later on and csvkit won't be useful

Note that my data are string and each value is encapsulated between quotes ". This may help to isolate the commas that need to be changed

I am very bad at this, thank you very much in advance for your help

Best,

Comment: Use `csvformat` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead: `csvformat -D '|' prod.csv > output.psv`

Comment: Thank you Shawn, but is there a solution using sed ?

Comment: Better to use a tool that understands the format than trying to hack something together using regular expressions. sed is only appropriate for the most trivial CSV; fields with embedded commas, quotes, newlines etc. are not that.

Comment: Ok I get the logic, it's just that I have other files with the same issues but in txt format and not csv

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/^([^"]*("[^",]*")*[^"]*"[^,"]*),/\1\n/;ta;y/,\n/|,/' file
```

Convert `,`'s within double quotes to newlines, then translate `,`'s to `|`'s and `\n`'s to `,`'s.

Answer (score 0):

What about using POSIX `awk`?

```
awk -v FS= -v OFS= \
'{
    for (c=0; c<NF; c++) {
        if ($c == "\"") {
            quoted = !quoted
        }

        if ($c == "," && !quoted) {
            $c = "|"
        }
    }

    print
}'
```

I’ve used this approach a number of times as a quick and dirty (and portable) csv parser.

It’s scanning every character, and tracking whether it’s inside or outside of double quotes. It’s fairly slow, but it does get the job done.

**Caveats:**

- It fails if quoted strings also contain escaped double quotes (`\"`), which some csv files do (your example data doesn’t). I think that could be fixed, but I haven’t got around to doing so.
- Any single, non paired quote (without a matching one) would also break it.
- Slow.